# How to save a file using Save File Dialog box in Odoo 10CE?

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to export some data in xls format.

```py
def export_to_xls(self):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('FileName'+fields.Date.context_today(self)+'.xls')
    // Skipped some code here.
```

The above code working fine and save the xls file in `/home/` directory.

Instead of specifying the path in the code, I need to open the browser's save file dialog box. How can I achieve this?

Comment: please, provide context scenario

Comment: Add the file as attachment to the document. Then return download action.